# Truffle : dotenv is not working in truffle.js

Tags: solidity, truffle, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle-migration

I am trying to get the seed words from the powershell command prompt. Hence I am using the 'dotenv' in truffle.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log('aa - process.env.MNEMONIC : '+mnemonic);
```

Later in powershell, I am issuing the command.

```
MNEMONIC="Let us code ICO" truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten
```

When I see the console log statement I see the value in "process.env.MNEMONIC " as undefined. Could you please help in resolve this error ?

[image]

**Option 2:**
I have created the .env file and tried to access it in the truffle.js as shown below. Still I am unable to access it. The value still shows as undefined.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not related to `dotenv`, the message tells you that `MNEMONIC=... is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`

You need to define `.env` file with `MNEMONIC` setting, or run command (Windows):

**Command Prompt**

```
set MNEMONIC=Let us code ICO && truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten
```

**PowerShell**

```
$env:MNEMONIC='Let us code ICO'; truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten
```

Comment: At line:1 char:30
+ set MNEMONIC=Let us code ICO &&  truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten
+                              ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

Comment: I have even tried with .env file. please see the edited question

Comment: @iappmaker name of the file should be `.env`

Comment: How about the error returned for this statement "set MNEMONIC=Let us code ICO && truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten"                                                                                                                               At line:1 char:30 + set MNEMONIC=Let us code ICO && truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten + ~~ The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version. + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

Comment: in PowerShell you need to execute something like: `set MNEMONIC='Let us code ICO'; truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten`

Comment: I tried set MNEMONIC='Let us code ICO'; truffle migrate. Still I am getting undefined only

Comment: @iappmaker take a look answer

Answer (score 2):

I think dotenv expects you to have an .env file rather than your envvariable.env file.